# calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier forIndexPath causes infinite loop

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I can't arbitrarily dequeue cells for calculating heights like I could with `UITableView`. What would be the equivalent way of doing this with a `UICollectionView`?

`dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` is calling `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. Which in return is calling `dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` etc..

I call `dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to be able to retrieve the height of the cells. I have many different cell sizes in my storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong, `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` should only be implemented if you are dynamically resizing the cells (that is, modifying the size specified in the Interface Builder, whether storyboard or xib).

If your cells are all sized from the interface builder, than you just don't need to implement that method.

Comment: The size of the items are set in the Collection Flow Layout in the storyboard so the height of the cells are the same even though they aren't supposed to be.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that if you DO implement this method, then you should not rely on `dequeueResuableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath` to get the size of the cell. It should rather depend on your data model (so maybe on what image goes in that cell)